# Add class to first post queried

Tags: terms

How would i add is-active class to the first `<li>` generated by the query ?    thank you I appreciate it.

```
<?php
    $_terms = get_terms( array('claim-accordion-type') );

    foreach ($_terms as $term) :

        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'         => 'claims_accordion',
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'claim-accordion-type',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term_slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                ));

        if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :

 echo'<li class="accordion-item " data-accordion-item>';

        echo'<a href="#" class="accordion-title">';
            echo ''. $term->name .'';

        echo'</a>';






            while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) : $_posts->the_post();





        ?>

    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>


      <a data-open="exampleModal1">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>


    </div>


    <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>


      <?php the_content(); ?>

        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>



    <?php
        endwhile;


   echo '</li>';
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();




    endforeach;
    ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe fix your formatting to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $_terms = get_terms( array('claim-accordion-type') );
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_terms as $term) :
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
    $_posts = new WP_Query( array(                        'post_type'         => 'claims_accordion',                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,                        'tax_query' => array(                            array(                                'taxonomy' => 'claim-accordion-type',                                'field'    => 'slug',                                'terms'    => $term_slug,                            ),                        ),                    ));

    if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $i++;

    if ( $i == 1 ) {
        $class = 'is-active';
    } else {
        $class = null;
    }

    echo'<li class="accordion-item ' . $class . '" data-accordion-item>';
    echo'<a href="#" class="accordion-title">';
    echo ''. $term->name .'';
    echo'</a>';
    while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
          <a data-open="exampleModal1">
            <h4><?php  the_title(); ?></h4></a>
        </div>
        <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
          <?php  the_content(); ?>
            <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    echo '</li>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way - instead of:

```
echo'<li class="accordion-item " data-accordion-item>';
```

use:

```
echo '<li class="accordion-item '.(!defined('firstp_created_444') && define('firstp_created_444',true) ? 'is-active' : '') .'" data-accordion-item>';
```